# How to create a 2D List in Python Based on Certain Values in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of the following values:

```
numbers = [127, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1, 127]
```

These all refer to a "capability" of a microcontroller pin, basically what "modes" are available.  The way the structure works is that the first number is a mode and the second number is a resolution, when a `127` is returned it means all the modes of that pin are exhausted.  So for example,

the third pin in this list supports modes `0, 1, 4` with resolutions `1, 1, 14`. Similarly the first two pins support no modes (which is why there are two consecutive `127`s).

My question is, how can I make a 2D list for all of the pins and their supported modes?  How can I loop through that list of numbers, adding a new list each time a `127` is reached?  Here is what I have so far:

```
    pins = []
    supported_modes = [] # Temporary list to hold values
    for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
            if numbers[i] == 127:
                pins.append(supported_modes) # Append to pin list
                del supported_modes[:]          
                return
            supported_modes.append(numbers[i])
```

However, this has all sorts of problems.  Mainly think that `supported_modes` is deleted each time.  Ideally this list (if filled with the first three pins only) would look like:

```
pins = [ [], [], [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14] etc. ]
```

Thanks

Comment: I wish all questions came in like this one. A brief but thorough explanation with a (nearly) working code snippet, applicable tags, an example of the desired result, and an obvious attempt at analyzing the problem yourself before turning to SO. Nice.

Comment: I have learned the hard way that taking a few seconds to formulate a question correctly really does help. I think people are so nice with their advice the least someone with a question can do is what you describe above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pins = []
supported_modes = []

for number in numbers:
    if number == 127:
        pins.append(supported_modes)
        supported_modes = []
    else:
        supported_modes.append(number)
```

You had a couple problems: the `return` should have been `continue` but I prefer `else`, and `del` wasn't useful there because as you said it wipes out `supported_modes` even after you inserted it, because in Python everything is by reference.

Comment: So am I correct that the reason that `supported_modes = []` does not overwrite the previous `supported_modes` (because in Python everything is reference) is that the `for` creates a new scope each time?

Comment: No, that's not why.  It works because `supported_modes` is a name, and `=` rebinds that name to a new list `[]`.  So the statement makes `supported_modes` refer to a new empty list, rather than deleting the contents of the old list which is still referenced elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [127, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1, 127]

answer = []
temp = []
for num in numbers:
    if num==127:
        answer.append(temp)
        temp = []
    else:
        temp.append(num)
if temp:
    answer.append(temp)
```

Output:

```
In [51]: answer
Out[51]: 
[[],
 [],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1]]
```

There's a solution with `itertools` as well:

```
import itertools

answer = []
while numbers:
    temp = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n!=127, numbers))
    numbers = numbers[len(temp)+1 :]
    answer.append(temp)
```

Output:

```
In [79]: answer
Out[79]: 
[[],
 [],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1]]  # note the missing empty list at the end
```

Comment: I like that the first answer does not have to import itertools but the empty list actually shouldn't be there.  the 127 signals that there are no more supported modes and accompanies every set of modes.  Is there a way to prevent it from appearing (not simply removing it after the fact) in the first case?

Comment: I am still not sure why you have the last `if temp` condition.  It seems like the accepted answer is simpler and accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: @Startec: if you're sure that the last entry in `numbers` will **always** be `127`, then you won't need the `if temp` statement. However, if you cannot make that guarantee, my answer is a little more robust

Answer (score 0):

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/11m)

#### Code:

```
numbers = [127, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1, 127, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1, 127]

pins = []
supported_modes = []
for number in numbers:
    if number == 127:
        if supported_modes:
            pins.append(supported_modes)
        supported_modes = []
    else:
        supported_modes.append(number)

print pins
```

#### Output:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 14],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 1]]
```